# When I knit my file I get a "Line 6 Error in .... could not find function %>%" message

Tags: r

When I try and knit my `R markdown`, I get a message saying

```
Line 6 Error in Q1%>% arrange(des(CO2_annual_tonnes))%>% filter(Year == 
2005) : could not find function %> %
```

Unsure what to do as it runs fine and no other error messages appear.

Comment: did you forget to add another `%` somewhere?, i.e `%>%`

Comment: Nope, just checked all of them and they all have %>%

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you post a little bit of your code as well. Try to put spaces around the pipe symbol `%>%`. from The error message it looks like those are missing. Might be the problem that `knitr` doesn't see that they belong together.

Comment: I think the section the error is in is the following:

Comment: Q1%>% 
  arrange(desc(CO2_annual_tonnes)) %>% 
  filter(Year == 2005)

Comment: I have spaces before each %>% and still getting the error message when I try and knit it as a html

Comment: Do you also have spaces after `%>%`? Also did you load the `dplyr` package in you rmd file?

Comment: I have got dplyr loaded. Just added a space after each %>% and the same message appears :(

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you explicitly load the `dplyr` package during your knitting process or did you load it beforehand into your environment. The latter won't work. You have to include something like ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dplry)
```
Edit: the ticks are not showing. It should be a normal codeblock in your rmd file

Comment: That was the problem! I have managed to fix this and my document knits now! Thank you so much!